# Getting friends picture using facebook-android-SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm getting friends ids and names using

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", new FriendRequestListener());
```

but I also need the friends profile pictures.
I could loop over the friends to get them, but this is many requests.

Is there any way to get friends ids, names AND pictures in one request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> Is there any way to get friends ids, names AND pictures in one request?

Yes, it's possible, using [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) and the [User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) and [Friend](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/) FQL tables:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic, pic_small, pic_big, FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

In your Android app you can make the FQL query like so:

```
String query = "SELECT uid, name, pic, pic_small, pic_big FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "fql.query");
params.putString("query", query);
mAsyncFacebookRunner.request(null, params, new CustomRequestListener());
```

where `CustomRequestListener()` extends `RequestListener` in the Facebook Android SDK.

This will return:

- id
- user name
- URLs for default, small and big profile images

for the current user's friends.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately not because friends list is a JSON encoded answer and including all pic would be a huge response.
You have to call `http://graph.facebook.com/ + userid + /picture?type=large` (omit `?type=large` if you want small sized version) for every friend.